# With ASP.NET viewstate, is there a best practice for when in the lifecycle to access the viewstate?

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

In building custom controls, I've seen two patterns for using the viewstate.  One is to use properties to disguise the viewstate access as persistent data.

```
   public bool AllowStuff
   {
       get
       {
           return (ViewState[constKeyAllowStuff] != null) ?
               (bool)ViewState[constKeyAllowStuff] : false;
       }
       set { ViewState[constKeyAllowStuff] = value; }
   }
```

The other is to use private member fields and to override the Load/SaveViewState methods on the control and handle it all explicitly:

```
 protected override object SaveViewState()
 {
     object[] myViewState = new object[2];
     myViewState[0] = base.SaveViewState();
     myViewState[1] = _allowStuff;
     return myViewState;
 }

 protected override void LoadViewState(object savedState)
 {
     object[] stateArray = (object[])savedState;
     base.LoadViewState(stateArray[0]);
     _allowStuff = (bool)stateArray[1];
 }
```

(I cut out a lot of safety checking for clarity, so just ignore that.)

Is there are particular advantage to one method over the other?  I can't see how they'd differ much performance wise. Version 1 is lazy, so I guess you save a bit if you don't need  that particular value during a pass.  Version 1 is also more abstract, hides the details better.  Version 2 is clearer about when the data is actually valid and ok to read or modify (between the load and save) because it more clearly works within the ASP.NET lifecycle.

Version 2 does tend to require more boilerplate code though (a property, a backing private field, and viewstate handling in two places) as opposed to Version 1 which combines all that into one place.

Thoughts then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The private member field approach is often used for objects who do not directly have access to the ViewState state bag.  So in a sense, I'd use option one for custom controls, user controls, or pages, or anything that has a ViewState or similar property, but use the other option for an object that does not directly have access to ViewState (like a class you want to be able to "serialize" and store in viewstate).  For instance, custom controls would use that approach to store state for child objects that do not directly reference viewstate.

HTH.

Comment: When working with webforms I would always follow the pattern of Property that wraps view state, and I'd pass that viewstate backed property around in my custom MVP pattern implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Fist of all I would use ControlState and not viewstate so it works correctly if in a container that has view state turned off.

Then i would override init, savecontrolstate, loadcontrolstate and databind.

and make sure to register that the control uses the control state i.e. Page.RegisterRequiresControlState(this)

oh and the advantage is that your control is more robust (user can't screw it up as easily) and will work when dynamically loaded and across postbacks "better"

Comment: I probably should use control state more, but I feel so dirty doing it. Like I'm accessing the secret, invulnerable viewstate. Actually, we do sometimes have issues with what you mentioned, how do you mean it will work better for dynamic loading and across postbacks?

Comment: basically, I just meant that if you write it correctly, it will still work, even if view state is turned off, even if it is in an update pannel, or there is a ajax callback, etc..

Comment: Though if you know you are going to be part of an ajax callback ScriptManager sm = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page);
     if (sm == null)
     {
          throw new InvalidOperationException("A ScriptManager is required on this page");
     }
     base.OnPreRender(e);
     ScriptManager.RegisterHiddenField(this, this.ClientStateID, "");